# how to disable automount of usb drive in ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: usb, automount, dconf

I tried [follow steps](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/20107) which worked in 18.04 but it does not work for 19.10:

```
    Create a file /etc/dconf/pofile/local with following content:
    # cat /etc/dconf/pofile/local
    user-db:user
    system-db:local

    Create a file /etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-media-automount with following content:

    # cat /etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-media-automount
    [org/gnome/desktop/media-handling]
    automount=false
    automount-open=false

    After creating the file, apply the changes using below command :

    # dconf update
```

In 18.04 we can find the new rules in `dconf dump /` but in 19.10 it does not show the newly added rules in local.d. `dconf-editor` still give true for those 2 values which are the defaults.

Any idea how to make the gnome respect local.d again?

Comment: Use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false` and `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false` in the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I just figured it out. The `DCONF_PROFILE` has to be set to the profile file name. Here it needs to be `local`. If it is not set, by default it is looking for `/etc/dconf/profile/user`. Thus change the file name to `user` is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

easier option: run dconf-editor, go to org.gnome.desktop.media-handling